# Что означает одно равно в условии javascript if (s = grid[o + i]) {}?

Tags: javascript, if, операторы

Не могу понять что делает интерпретатор, когда в условии стоить один знак

равенства (`if (s = grid[o + i]) {}`):

```
function far(x, y) {
  var i = x / cellSize | 0,
      j = y / cellSize | 0,
      i0 = Math.max(i - 2, 0),
      j0 = Math.max(j - 2, 0),
      i1 = Math.min(i + 3, gridWidth),
      j1 = Math.min(j + 3, gridHeight);

  for (j = j0; j < j1; ++j) {
    var o = j * gridWidth;
    for (i = i0; i < i1; ++i) {
      if (s = grid[o + i]) {
        var s,
            dx = s[0] - x,
            dy = s[1] - y;
        if (dx * dx + dy * dy < radius2) {
          gConnection.append("line")
              .attr("x1", x)
              .attr("y1", y)
              .attr("x2", x)
              .attr("y2", y)
            .transition()
              .attr("x2", s[0])
              .attr("y2", s[1]);

          return false;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

[Код](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/dbb02448b0f93e4c82c3)

[Операторы сравнения](https://javascript.ru/comparison-operators)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Таким способом проверяется, что в `grid` есть элемент с индексом `o + i`.

Данный подход считается плохим стилем кода, но его осознанно могут применить, если хотят экономить байты объема кода.

Answer (score 3):

Это обычное присвоение, просто оно отрабатывает в условии `if`, результатом которого будет `true`, вот упрощенный пример:

```js
console.log(s); // undefined
if (s = 1 + 1) {
  var s;
  console.log(s); // 2
}
console.log(s); // 2
```

Мне кажется это неправильный подход и его стоит избегать, в данном случае этот `if` будет выполнятся всегда и просто лишняя вложенность в коде.